# How to pass array index with HTML onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

This function takes an argument (an object containing containing the player's attributes)

```
const yourTeam = [];

function selectingYourTeam(player) {
  yourTeam.push(player);
  alert(yourTeam[0].name);
  return;
}
```

This for loop creates an HTML table, that contains all the players you can select from.

```
for (i = 0; i < playerPool.length; i++) {
  document.write('<tr><td>' + playerPool[i].name + '</td><td>' + playerPool[i].region + 
  '</td><td>' + playerPool[i].skills["Offence"] + '</td><td>' +   
  playerPool[i].skills["Defence"]
  + '</td><td>' + playerPool[i].playerID + '</td><td><button type="button"
  onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[0])">Select Player</button></td></tr>');
}
```

The problem is that when `onclick` receives `i` the `alert()`returns `undefined`. However, it works as expected when I give it `[0]`, so I know that logic is working. Regardless, it must receive `i` in order for it to be purposeful.

`<button type="button" onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[0])">Select Player</button>`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: How did you use `i`?

Comment: I suspect you put a literal `i` in the string instead of the value of `i`.

Comment: Did you do `onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[i])"`, or `onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[${i}])"`

Comment: @Unmitigated These are the relevant code snippets. Do you want the whole 125 lines so you can reproduce it? Seriously?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette "i" is referring to the count in the "for" loop.

Comment: @this is exactly what I suspected myself. How do I pass the variable as a value in this situation? I have tried `<button type="button" onclick="selectingYourTeam(' + playerPool[i] + )">Select Player</button>` to no avail.

Comment: @mstephen19 Does `$` indicate JQuery? I'm writing vanilla JS.

Comment: `${someVariable}` is [templating litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Try `onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[' + i + '])"`... Because you only want the `i` to be used in the string. Not the `playerPool[i]` object.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Does `$` does indicate a JQuery statement? I'm writing vanilla JS.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette You did it Louys! You are one smart cookie! You should officially answer my question so I can throw some reputation your way!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you so much! I will definitely explore template literals ASAP. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexDev No. That is vanilla JS - it's called template literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was wrong with

```
'<button type="button" onclick="selectingYourTeam(' + playerPool[i] + ')">Select Player</button>'
```

is you were putting the object inside the string, instead of the value of `i` only.
That problably was ending like

```
<button type="button" onclick="selectingYourTeam(Object[object])">Select Player</button>
```

So go with this:

```
'<button type="button" onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[' + i + '])">Select Player</button>'
```

Or using [template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (which I suggest you to explore) that would be:

```js
document.write(`
<tr><td>
  ${playerPool[i].name}
</td><td>
  ${playerPool[i].region}
</td><td>
  ${playerPool[i].skills["Offence"]}
</td><td>
  ${playerPool[i].skills["Defence"]}
</td><td>
  ${playerPool[i].playerID}
</td><td>
  <button type="button" onclick="selectingYourTeam(playerPool[${i}])">Select Player</button>
</td></tr>`);
```